# JQuery and textarea width: css() method

Tags: jquery, css, textarea

I have an textarea with tinyMCE included in the JQuery dialog.

Here is how I created this:

```
tinyMCE.init({ mode: 'none', });    
var paragraphDialog = $('#paragraph_dialog');       
$('<textarea/>').attr('id', 'txt_paragraph');
txtAreaParagraph = $('<textarea/>');    
paragraphDialog = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'paragraph_dialog');
txtAreaParagraph.appendTo(paragraphDialog);

paragraphDialog.dialog({
    height: 300,
    width: 800,
    modal: true,
open: function ()
    {
    if ($('#txt_paragraph_parent', $(this)).length == 0)
        {
        var ddd = {mode:'none'};
        txtAreaParagraph.tinymce(ddd);
        }
    };
```

Now, I would like to set the width attribute of the textarea.

I have tried

```
$('<textarea/>').css('width', '700px');
```

and

```
$('<textarea/>').css('width', '700');
```

But none of them works.

Thank you very much for your help regarding my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
txtAreaParagraph = $('<textarea/>');  
txtAreaParagraph.css('width', '700px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the tags , do :

```
$('textarea').css('width', '700');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ftom2, but this is not changing my problem, I have tryed but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the width parameter to the tinyMCE.init function like so.

```
tinyMCE.init({width: "800", mode: 'none', });    
var paragraphDialog = $('#paragraph_dialog');       
$('<textarea/>').attr('id', 'txt_paragraph');
txtAreaParagraph = $('<textarea/>');    
paragraphDialog = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'paragraph_dialog');
txtAreaParagraph.appendTo(paragraphDialog);

paragraphDialog.dialog({
    height: 300,
    width: 800,
    modal: true,
open: function ()
    {
    if ($('#txt_paragraph_parent', $(this)).length == 0)
        {
        var ddd = {width: "800", mode:'none'};
        txtAreaParagraph.tinymce(ddd);
        }
    };
```